# Parallelogram, Area and Angles

Tags: geometry

Just wondering if someone can confirm if I am on the right track to calculate the area of a parallelogram if only been given the co-ordinates of the four points.

So, for example, starting (bottom left and working anti clockwise) with Point A (10, 5), Point B (20,5), Point C (25,10), Point D (13,10).

Do I first work out the height by using Points A and D, the difference in the y co-ord is 10-5 =10.  Then the difference in the x coord id 13-10 = 3.  So atan (5/3) ~ 59.  Then for the Area = Adjacent Side *Adjacent Side * Sin Angle.  (so 5*5*Sin 59) ~21.43

Is this correct ?

Comment: $ABCD$ is not a parallelogram, and $10-5=5$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right. One can use the formula of the cross product to calculate the area of the parallelogram. The formula looks like the following:

$$||\vec{AD} \times \vec{AB}|| = ||\vec{AD}||\cdot \|\vec{AB}||\cdot sin(\angle(\vec{AD}, \vec{AB}))$$
 2. The angle is: $$\angle(\vec{AD}, \vec{AB}) = asin\frac{||\vec{AD} \times \vec{AB}||}{||\vec{AD}||\cdot \|\vec{AB}||}$$